# HTML/JQuery: A div with a scrolling backgrounds that never ends?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I have a div element of width 400px and a background-image of width 2000px.
I want this background image to scroll sideways endlessly, it must never reach and end because the bg image is set to repeat (HTML does this by default I think).

I thought of doing something like this but I dont know if it's the right way:

```
$("#divWithScrollingBackground").animate({"background-position-x" : 999999999}, 999);
```

Comment: I would caution against this. It seems to be a usability nightmare for your visitors.  They might think something is wrong, given the scrolling never stops.

Comment: What are you talking about??? It works like a <marquee> but you cant do marquee with background images. Do you think something is wrong when you see a marquee?

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  Well, a marquee is something different than what I was thinking when I read your description.  Still not sure this is the method you want to use, though.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the uncertainty of how long (and how far) the animation must run, you can do this with a single-cycle animation with "flyback-repeat". This is more like the way tickers are generally coded.

```
function bgScroll() {
    $("#x").animate({
        'backgroundPosition': '-2000px 0'
    }, 4000, 'linear', function() {
        $(this).css("backgroundPosition", '0 0');
        setTimeout(bgScroll, 0);
    });
};
bgScroll();
```

You will need to use [this jQuery plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/) to get bg animation to work cross-browser.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BebXz/).

Adjust my `4000` milliseconds to give  the speed that you want (smaller number = faster animation).

'linear' is important to give as smooth a transition as possible at flyback. I think the jQuery default 'swing' easing would give an odd effect but by all means try it.